# Auto scroll to one of SliverList items when a Tab is pressed

Tags: flutter

I have a stateful widget with tabs at the top and has a list below it. The list is subdivided into different categories. Each category is listed into each tab. What I want to do is when an item is pressed in the tab, I want its corresponding category in the list to scroll to view.

Here is the relevant code for reference:

```
SliverPersistentHeader(
  pinned: true,
  delegate: _SliverAppBarTabDelegate(
    child: Container(
      child: TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        labelColor: Colors.black,
        tabs: createTabList(),
        controller: tabBarController,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (context, index) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: kSpacerRegular),
        child: RestaurantMenuCard(menuCard: menuCards[index]),
      );
    },
    childCount: menuCards.length,
  ),
),
```

I searched all day looking for a solution but could not find one. I also tried this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index) but does not seem to work in my case.

Here is my 'widget tree' for more context:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(),
        SliverPersistentHeader(),
        SliverList(),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

A screen capture for more context

[image]

Comment: I need my slivers to scroll as one.  So my RestaurantMenuCards (children of the SliverList) need to be not scrollable on its own.

Comment: I updated the question for more context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the issue with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview/49154882#49154882). I replaced `SliverList` with `SliverToBoxAdapter`. The child  is the list of my `RestaurantMenuCard` in a `Column`. Thus, the resulting widget tree is:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(),
        SliverPersistentHeader(),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          Column(
            RestaurantMenuCard(),
            RestaurantMenuCard(),
            ...
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

The magic happens when I added a global key to each instance of the `RestaurantMenuCard` as discussed in the linked answer.

Then finally, I trigger the `Scrollable.ensureVisible(context)` in `onTap` function of my `TabBar`.

Comment: It's not a solution, but a hacky workaround. You've just got rid of SliverList and use a basic Column. It doesn't reply to the question "how to scroll to a certain SliverList item".